# Return function in for loop only returns 1 item

Tags: python, function, discord, return, discord.py

I'm creating a Discord Bot. In the Bot, I am wanting to make a command that prints out the standings.
Here is the code:

```
rec= {'Boston': '3-0', 'Dallas': '2-1', 'Seattle': '0-3'}
def standings():
  for team, win in rec.items():
    return('{}: {}'.format(team, win))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if msg.startswith(".standings"):
    s = standings()
    await message.channel.send(s)
```

The Output:

```
Boston: 3-0
```

Expected Output:

```
Boston 3-0
Dallas 2-1
Seattle 0-3
```

How can I make the function return all of the items, and not just one?
Also, if I wanted to ping roles that have the same name as the Teams, how would I go about doing that? I tried to put an @ before the "s", but the outcome did not ping the role.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `return` exits the function, so the loop stops immediately.

Comment: A function can return only once. You can either prepare the data in a list comprehension or make it a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def standings():
    rows = ['{}: {}'.format(team, win) for team, win in rec.items()]
    return '\n'.join(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` in the for-loop exits the `standings` function in the first iteration of the loop. That's why you only see the first standing in your output.

If you want the function to return a single string containing all standings, you can do the following:

```
def standings():
    return ', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(team, win) for team, win in rec.items()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use generators as mentioned above.

```
rec = {'Boston': '3-0', 'Dallas': '2-1', 'Seattle': '0-3'}

def standings():
    for team, win in rec.items():
        yield '{}: {}'.format(team, win)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.startswith(".standings"):
    for s in standings():
        await message.channel.send(s)
```